# Configure iPhone to send smaller pictures as e-mail attachment?

Tags: iphone, mail.app, email, photos

A friend has an iPhone whose camera she uses with the default settings of 2592x1936 pixels, which is pretty big when attaching pictures in e-mails. The files are very big and I need to scroll down/right to view the whole picture.

I don't own an iPhone, and was wondering if it's possible to reconfigure it to:

1. Save local pictures as eg. 1024x768 (it's big enough when viewing pictures on a computer)
2. After saving a picture locally, making a smaller copy, eg. 640x480, and send that smaller copy as an e-mail attachment?

Can the iPhone do this, or is there an application that can do this?

Comment: I am not sure, if you can do it on the iPhone. Though you can do this in Photoshop and probably GIMP, which is free.

Comment: @TheBro21, it's very easy to do on the iPhone - see below. I'm sure that there are apps that would also facilitate the process if that was needed as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You do it right at the point of sending an email…
right after you hit send, this screen appears…

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'll ask here why she doesn't select Small when attaching a picture to an e-mail.